How to mount a hard drive that suddenly was disconnected after zipping some files?
I mounted my hard drive and was zipping some files and the hard drive got disconnected suddenly.
Then I plugged it out and inserted again and tried to mount a partition but nothing works. Data is important. How to retrieve it?
Then I get this:
[user@fedora ~]$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/hdd2/
mount: /mnt/hdd2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
       dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

dmesg says
[12204.899870] exFAT-fs (sda2): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[12205.060652] exFAT-fs (sda2): failed to load alloc-bitmap
[12205.060660] exFAT-fs (sda2): failed to recognize exfat type

Running fsck on the partition:
[user@fedora mnt]$ sudo fsck.exfat /dev/sda2 
exfatprogs version : 1.2.5
failed to read bitmap
failed to verify root directory.
/dev/sda2: clean. directories 1, files 0

However badblocks (only performed read-only) doesn't report any badblocks.
System info
fastfetch
[user@fedora ~]$ fastfetch
             .',;::::;,'.                 user@fedora
         .';:cccccccccccc:;,.             -----------
      .;cccccccccccccccccccccc;.          OS: Fedora Linux 40 (KDE Plasma) x86_64
    .:cccccccccccccccccccccccccc:.        Host: 82SB (IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH7)
  .;ccccccccccccc;.:dddl:.;ccccccc;.      Kernel: Linux 6.10.12-200.fc40.x86_64
 .:ccccccccccccc;OWMKOOXMWd;ccccccc:.     Uptime: 3 hours, 37 mins
.:ccccccccccccc;KMMc;cc;xMMc;ccccccc:.    Packages: 2518 (rpm)
,cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cc;;WW:;cccccccc,    Shell: bash 5.2.26
:cccccccccccccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc:    Display (AUOD1ED): 1920x1080 @ 60 Hz (as 1601x900) in 16″ [Built-in]
:ccccccc;oxOOOo;MMM000k.;cccccccccccc:    DE: KDE Plasma 6.2.0
cccccc;0MMKxdd:;MMMkddc.;cccccccccccc;    WM: KWin (Wayland)
ccccc;XMO';cccc;MMM.;cccccccccccccccc'    WM Theme: Breeze
ccccc;MMo;ccccc;MMW.;ccccccccccccccc;     Theme: Breeze (Dark) [Qt], Breeze [GTK3/4]
ccccc;0MNc.ccc.xMMd;ccccccccccccccc;      Icons: breeze [Qt], breeze [GTK3/4]
cccccc;dNMWXXXWM0:;cccccccccccccc:,       Font: Noto Sans (10pt) [Qt], Noto Sans (10pt) [GTK3/4]
cccccccc;.:odl:.;cccccccccccccc:,.        Cursor: breeze (24px)
ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc:'.          Terminal: kitty 0.36.4
:ccccccccccccccccccccccc:;,..             Terminal Font: JetBrainsMonoNF-Regular (12pt)
 ':cccccccccccccccc::;,.                  CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 6600H (12) @ 4.56 GHz
                                          GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Mobile [Discrete]
                                          GPU 2: AMD Radeon 660M [Integrated]
                                          Memory: 4.53 GiB / 14.81 GiB (31%)
                                          Swap: 0 B / 8.00 GiB (0%)
                                          Disk (/): 152.15 GiB / 464.17 GiB (33%) - btrfs
                                          Local IP (enp2s0): 192.168.118.114/22
                                          Battery (PABAS0241231): 78% [AC Connected]
                                          Locale: en_US.UTF-8

                                                                  
                                                                  

uname
Linux fedora 6.10.12-200.fc40.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Sep 30 21:38:25 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

os-release
[user@fedora ~]$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Fedora Linux"
VERSION="40 (KDE Plasma)"
ID=fedora
VERSION_ID=40
VERSION_CODENAME=""
PLATFORM_ID="platform:f40"
PRETTY_NAME="Fedora Linux 40 (KDE Plasma)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;38;2;60;110;180"
LOGO=fedora-logo-icon
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:40"
DEFAULT_HOSTNAME="fedora"
HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f40/system-administrators-guide/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://ask.fedoraproject.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=40
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=40
SUPPORT_END=2025-05-13
VARIANT="KDE Plasma"
VARIANT_ID=kde



"Data is important" => Create a backup. Get a larger drive onto which you can create a disk image of the malfunctioning file system.  2) Get local help. The problem here is likely to be very hard to solve by the people on superuser.com (remotely). 3) Google "Testdisk"

